# Why "cylinder sets"?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

If $I$ is any set of indexes, we define $E^I=\{(x_i)_{i\in I}:x_i\in E\,\,\forall i\in I\}$, $E$ being any set. Subsets of $E^I$ of the form $C_J=\{x_i\in B_i\,\,\forall i\in J\}$, where $B_i\in\mathcal{A}\,\,\forall i\in J$, $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $J\subseteq I$ is finite, are called "cylinder sets", and form a basis of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}^{\otimes I}$. Why are these sets called "cylinder sets"? What is the origin of this name?

Comment: Hint: see what (visually) happens when we deal with $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The cylinder sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are products of borel sets of the real line. For example rectangles, i.e. products of intervals. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the cylinder sets are parallelepipeds. So @Kolmin why not "rectangles", "generalized rectangles", "rectangle sets" or "parallelepiped sets"?

Comment: Don't shoot the messanger... I did not invent the terminology. :D Btw, behind jokes, the hint I gave you is exactly the one I found in a book to see why cylinder sets are called in such a way. Moreover, regarding your terminology, it sounds a bit problematic, because – take $\Re^2$ for example – cylinder sets are not bounded above and below, i.e. they are not actually rectangles. Indeed, they are _cylinders_. ;)

Comment: To me, a cylinder is a solid with circular basis extending in the third dimension for a possibly infinite height. This can be seen as a rotation solid, thus matching [this definiton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry)). Now obviously you can get cylinders as cylinder sets if you view $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the product of the plane and the line, as a circle is Borel in the plane and the third dimension is an interval. However, if $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the product of three lines, it is not straightforward to get a cylinder, since you have to first create the circle.

Comment: Indeed, even as plane times line, you have to select a basis of the planar Borels which may seem less "simple" than the rectangles. And a rectangle to me can have one or even two infinite sides. Now I've seen the disambiguation page on Wikipedia, but the link "Cylinder (algebra)" sends me to cartesian products. Perhaps there is another use of the word cylinder which I have never heard of. @What say you @Kolmin? From your comment it most definitely seems so.

Comment: I do see your point, and most probably you are right. Actually, I do not even enter in the discussion. If you prefer, forget my second comment (in which I tried to "motivate" the usage of a certain expression in a more specific way) and stick to the first one. As I previously wrote, the reason I gave you there is exactly the one I found in a book to give the intuition behind the usage of that expression. Frankly, in the end it does not really matter if those objects are called "cylinder sets" or "gibberish sets", as long as we know how to use them. ;)

Comment: I also just started wondering about this nomenclature, and I'm totally spitballing here, but is there some polar-coordinate construction in which the name makes more sense? But even then, it seems you would have cylinders in one direction and semi-planes in the other, hm...

Comment: @MrArsGravis . In geometry a cylinder is $D\times \mathbb R$ where $D$ is a disc. In measure theory the disc can be anthing. That's it. In maths it is futile to get headaches about nomenclature.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is as simple as I wrote in my comment just now.

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry for commenting on an older post but what is the definition of a disk in measure theory? The fact that a disk can be anything is new to me.

Comment: @CBBAM The comment section is for comments, regardless how old the post is. If you read carefully though I never said that in measure theory $D$ needs to be a disk. So the question what a disk is in measure theory is irrelevant.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your response. So you are saying that the cylinder can be defined as $D \times \mathbb{R}$ where $D$ can be any set?

Comment: What a cylinder set is in measure theory is correctly defined in OP. I tried to give an example of one that is fairly close to a geometric cylinder: $D\times \mathbb R$ where $D$ can be any set. This is not a definition but an *example*. BTW: this entire saga is about nomenclature "cylinder". If you follow my comments you will frequently see that I am not a big fan of endless nomenclature discussions. Things need to be baptized and could be baptized differently. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the origin of this name?

Here is my guess (this is essentially what I was told in one of my lectures and what Kurt G. wrote in the comments):

If $|J|=1$, i.e. $J=\{i\}$ for some $i\in I$, then the cylinder sets are simply the preimages of measurable subsets of $E$ w.r.t. the projection$$\pi_i:E^I\to E.$$Now why are the preimages of a projection called cylinder sets? Of course this is motivated by a very specific example:

Let $E^3$ be a $3$-dim. [euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Technical_definition) and $E^2$ a $2$-dim. subspace. Now we can consider the obvious projection $E^3\to E^2$ (i.e. $x\in E^3$ is mapped to the intersection of $E^2$ and the line through $x$ perpendicular to $E^2$) and in this case it should be clear why the preimages are referred to as cylinders: At least the preimages of circles in $E^2$ are (infinite) cylinders in the usual sense.

In case that you complain that $E^3$ is not a product space: Pick any 1-dim. subspace $E^1$ orthogonal to $E^2$ and consider the obvious bijection $E^1\times E^2\to E^3$.